# Como trabalhar com media queries CSS?

Tags: css, media-queries

Gostaria de uma informação sobre como usar *media queries*.

Como faço para definir *media* de um site nas abaixo?

- 2560 x 1440
- 2560 x 1080
- 1920 x 1080
- 1366 x 768
- 1280 x 1024
- 1280 x 768

Sendo que meu site é estendido a tela toda, ele é um layout que o *height* não desce fazendo barra lateral, e eu puxo a media pelo *height*.

Exemplo:

```css
@media screen and (min-height:768px) and (max-height:1080px){
    ...
}
```

Usar os valores `2560 x 1440`, `2560 x 1080`, `1920 x 1080`, `1366 x 768` e `1280 x 768` causa conflitos no *media*.

Como resolver?

Comment: Uma observação para outros users: se o site rola na vertical (que não é seu caso, pelo texto), você deve usar o `width` para fazer as queries, e não o `height`. Só faz sentido calibrar o media na vertical para coisas que tenham rolagem horizontal, (ou nenhuma, como na pergunta) ou para elementos específicos da página como navegação, etc, e não para o layout todo. Em casos extremos, dá pra usar juntos o width e o height no mesmo query, mas geralmente é exagero. TALVEZ no caso da pergunta em específico, seja a solução.

Answer (score 4):

Separe as medidas horizontais e vericais de cada elememnto em suas respectivas *queries* horizontais e verticais:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1280px)
   ... aqui voce põe larguras e posições horizontais dos elementos ...
   #minhadiv {width: 400px; left: 10px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1366px)
   ... aqui voce põe larguras e posições horizontais dos elementos ...
   #minhadiv {width: 450px; left: 15px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px)
   ... aqui voce põe larguras e posições horizontais dos elementos ...
   #minhadiv {width: 600px; left: 20px;}
}

@media screen and (min-height:768px)
   ... aqui voce põe alturas e posições verticais dos elementos ...
   #minhadiv {height: 200px; top: 10px;}
}

@media screen and (min-height:1080px)
   ... aqui voce põe alturas e posições verticais dos elementos ...
   #minhadiv {height: 300px; top: 20px;}
}
```

Se precisar de alguma combinação especial, basta usar as duas medidas juntas, mas cuidado que, ao ser muito específico, fica mais complicado de localizar problemas:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1366px) and (min-height:1080px)
   #minhadiv {width: 200px; height: 300px; left:80px; top: 20px; color:#eee ... }
}
```