# Como centralizar conteúdo na tela consoante o dispositivo móvel com o intel xdk?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, app, intel-xdk

Boa noite,

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação móvel com o intel XDK com framework do bootstrap, preciso de saber como posso colocar o meu conteúdo centralizado na tela em cada tipo de smartphone e resolução que não estou a conseguir fazer no iphone 4s fica bem mas por exemplo no iphone 6 plus fica um espaço grande em baixo branco.

```
<style>
        /* following three (cascaded) are equivalent to above three meta viewport statements */
        /* see http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/05/html5_dev_conf.html */
        /* see http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/ */
            @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }          @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
            @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }                   @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }
            /*@-ms-viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }   @viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }*/
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deveria dar uma olha de como trabalhar com `media queries`, como já explicado nessa [pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19342/22418) aqui do SOpt.

Para achar a resolução especifica do device que você deseja trabalhar, pode usar o [cssmediaqueries.com](http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/)

Comment: O programa ja me adiciona isso o que tenho definido e o que coloquei na pergunta que editei eu tenho de trabalhar não com um aparelho especifico mas em geral