# Como trabalhar com @media em css?

Tags: css, html5

Saudação para todos,

sou novo como programação em Frond-End, e estou começando a aprender a mexer com @media para aplicar chaveamento em uma pagina simples,mas o que seria cheveamento?

Criei um site responsivo quando a pagina tem mais de 991px de largura ele aparece o menu, porém quando ele tem menos de 991px aparece um ícone de três barrinhas, e se o usuário quer que apareça o menu estando a menos de 991px ele terá que clicar no ícone para aparecer o menu, como mostro na figura abaixo;

Menu acima de 991px;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora o menu a baixo de 991px sem clicar no ícone.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora o menu quando clicar no ícone.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que preciso na verdade é mudar e tira o sublinhado quando passo o mouse, a parte do código responsável por isso seria esse;

```
@media(max-width: 991px){

    .menu{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 200px;
        display: none;
        background-color: #bfbfbf;

        border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    }

    .menu a{
        text-decoration: none; 
    }

    .menu--exibindo{
        display: block;
    }

    .menu_item{
        display: block;
        line-height: 3;
    }
}
```

Mais especificamente essa parte do código referente ao que foi mostrado logo em cima;

```
.menu a{
        text-decoration: none; 
    }
```

O problema é que esse código como mostra em cima não faz alteração no menu, era para fazer, eu não sei aonde estou errado.

Deixarei o meu código fonte completo que está no GitHub disponivel para melhores esclarecimentos.

[BASTA CLICAR AQUI](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/HTML-project/blob/master/Condonager/css/componentes.css)

Comment: Relacionada/duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19342/129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você deseja retirar o sublinhado do menu lateral que aparece ao clicar no ícone do menu responsivo, simplesmente tem que usar o css: (baixei e funcionou em localhost)

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
.menu a {text-decoration: none;}
}
```

Caso queira tirar este sublinhado do menu em telas maiores, use o css:

```
.menu a {text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o seu problema não está no media query. Para mudar a propriedade de sublinhado quando passa o mouse, você tem que selecionar o atributo `hover` do CSS (que é a estilização responsável para quando os elementos terão o mouse em cima deles)

O seu código dentro do media query tem que ficar assim então:

```
.menu a:hover{
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```