# Alinhamento de imagem com Layouts responsivos

Tags: css, layout

Estou trabalhando em uma loja virtual e estou usando o site Nuvemshop para desenvolver a página na internet.

Só que estou enfrentando um problema ao posicionar o logo da loja no site.

Como o layout é responsivo eu preciso alinhar o logo da loja ao centro da página, então eu aplico um código de alinhamento no css na classe da imagem, mas o alinhamento no desktop fica de uma maneira e no mobile fica de outra e nunca ficam alinhados exatamente ao centro nos dois dispositivos, quando alinha em um, desalinha no outro.

Este é o código CSS que usei:

.logo-img{
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin-left: 40%;

}

E este é o link da minha página:

https://madcandydecorkids.lojavirtualnuvem.com.br/

Tentei selecionar outras classes, para ver se conseguia trabalhar com uma classe para o desktop e outra classe para o mobile, mas infelizmente todas as classes que selecionei, da maneira como fiz nenhuma resolveu este meu problema de alinhamento, aqui é minha última opção.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com isso, ficarei muito grato, desde já agradeço a toda equipe.

Answer (score 0):

Sua logo está centralizada! Seu container é que não tem 100% da largura, por isso da a impressão do desalinhamento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma forma de fazer ela "centralizar" na tela é usar um text-align:center na div onde a imagem esta dentro `<div id="logo" class="mobile-logo-home logo-img-container " style="text-align: center;">` e usar `transform:translateX` de 50% (ou seja, de 50% da largura) na imagem da logo, e retire esse margin-left:40% que tem lá não vai precisar mais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas obviamente vc pode precisar remover esse `translate` em telas menores. Para isso vc vai precisar usar media queries, sugiro que leia essa resposta, vai te ajudar com isso. [Como trabalhar com media queries CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19342/como-trabalhar-com-media-queries-css)