# Posicionar DIV no centro da página

Tags: css, html5, css3

Como eu faço para alinhar a div com fundo preto e transparente onde contém os botões no centro da página independente da resolução do monitor?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou usando é esse:

```
.fundo{
    background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.7);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}

<div class="col-md-12 fundo" align="center"> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary">ACESSO CONSULTOR</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">ACESSO GERENTE</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida, já está centralizado

Comment: Olá Rafael. Mas gostaria de ajustar o código para que fique compatível em outras resoluções. Não sou muito bom em CSS e não sei se o código que estou usando está certo.

Comment: Você está usando alguma framework front-end?

Comment: Olá Lukas. Estou usando o Bootstrap, mas a div que contém os botões ficam logo após a tag body

Comment: talvez isso te ajude um pouco, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8602/como-deixar-estas-divs-responsivas

Comment: Centralize qualquer coisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252419/8063

Answer (score 8):

#### Tempos modernos

Atualmente é possível fazer isto de maneira muito mais simples utilizando `flex-box`, exemplo:

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-box {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}

.content-box {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box container-box">
  <div class="content-box">Conteúdo alinhado<br> verticalmente</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Velhos tempos

Para alinhar um elemento verticalmente no centro da tela, apenas com CSS ele precisa ter altura fixa, exemplo:

```css
#centro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.7);
  color: white;
  
  /* pura mágica */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* posiciona na metade da tela */
  margin-top: -25px; /* e retrocede metade da altura */
}
```

```html
<div id="centro">Hello World</div>
```

Para alinhar horizontalmente a lógica é a mesma:

```css
#centro {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.7);
  color: white;
  
  /* pura mágica */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* posiciona na metade da tela */
  margin-top: -25px; /* e retrocede metade da altura */
  left: 50%; /* posiciona na metade da tela */
  margin-left: -100px; /* e retrocede metade da largura */
}
```

```html
<div id="centro">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Existem várias técnicas, as duas que eu gosto mais são as que vou citar porque elas não dependem de tamanho fixo.

Técnica 1 com `transform:translate`

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(https://www.placecage.com/c/500/500) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.centro {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.conteudo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="centro">
    <div class="conteudo"></div>
</div>
```

Técnica 2, essa eu acho muito boa, porque usa `display:flex` e você consegue fazer o `margin:auto` funcionar tanto na largura quanto na altura!

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(https://www.placecage.com/c/500/500) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.centro {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.conteudo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centro">
    <div class="conteudo"></div>
</div>
```

[]´s

Comment: hugocsl, sou eu fã. No CSS é você e @Sam.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. Haha valeu meu jovem, mas vou te contar uma coisa... Tem uns monstros escondidos aqui no site que manjam até mais que a gente rss. []'s 

Comment: hugocsl, sem querer abusar. Mas eu estou aplicando estilização em uma página em modo impressão (media print). Gostaria de saber se tem como eu utilizar duas estilizações, uma para modo retrato e outra para modo paisagem (No caso, utilizar uma media query para cada talvez. Ou um outro modo). Seria para exibição de gráficos. Se você puder me ajudar, ou me indicar uma pergunta que tenha uma resposta sua que responda esse meu questionamento, você poderia linká-la aqui. Ou eu abro uma pergunta sobre o tema. Obrigado!

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. sem maiores detalhes não consigo te ajudar muito, mas da uma olhada nessas duas resposta, lá eu falo de como pegar a orientação do dispositivo se está em portrait ou landscape https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396278/como-detectar-largura-da-tela-menor-que-a-altura-com-css/396282#396282 e aqui tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292233/bloquear-modo-paisagem-via-css-na-visualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pelo-celular/292236#292236 essa é a lista de tudo que ká respondi aqui sobre impressão e CSS https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A97477+print as vezes te ajuda tb

Comment: Me ajudou lá, cara. Valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, nesta foto de fundo, defina o tamanho dela em
width 100%.

Em seguida:

```
.fundo{
background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.7);
margin: auto;
}

<div class="col-md-12 fundo" align="center"> 
<button class="btn btn-primary">ACESSO CONSULTOR</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">ACESSO GERENTE</button>
</div>
```