# Bloquear modo paisagem,via Css, na visualização pelo celular

Tags: css3

Estou fazendo um projeto, e preciso bloquear o modo "paisagem",em uma tela específica (tela de login), eu quero que ao fazer o login, apareça uma mensagem para usuário para ele usar o modo paisagem, para assim melhor visualizar o sistema.

Alguém tem alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago acho que bloquear completamente vc só consegue com JavaScript.

Mas vc pode tratar o CSS dessa forma por exemplo

```
<meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled">
```

E criar um .CSS específico para cada tipo de orientação.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/paisagem.css" media="screen and (orientation: landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/retrato.css" media="screen and (orientation: portrait)">
```

Se vc quiser mostrar uma mensagem apenas quando o Celular estiver em modo paisagem vc ainda pode fazer dessa forma por exemplo:

```
#minha-mensagem {
    display none;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #minha-mensagem {
        display block;
    }
}
```

- Link de referencia para vc ver mais sobre os @media e orientação de tela https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Thiagão que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.