# Como detectar largura da tela menor que a altura com CSS?

Tags: css, orientation

Tenho uma div com `position: fixed` que ocupa toda a tela e que só é exibida quando a largura da tela for menor que a altura. Com JavaScript eu consigo fazer essa verificação e mostrar ou ocultar essa div de acordo com o critério acima, ou seja, **largura da tela < altura**. Isso é para forçar o usuário a usar o dispositivo na orientação horizontal (landscape) em uma página específica:

```js
window.onresize = window.onload = function(){
   
   if(this.innerWidth < this.innerHeight){
      document.getElementById("aviso").style.display = "flex";
   }else{
      document.getElementById("aviso").style.display = "none";
   }
   
}
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#aviso{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   display: none;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background: black;
   color: white;
}

#aviso strong{
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="aviso">
  <strong>Use o dispositivo na orientação horizontal!</strong>
</div>
<div id="main">
   Conteúdo
</div>
```

Ao executar o código acima e reduzir a largura da tela até que seja menor que a altura, a div `#aviso` é exibida por cima do conteúdo da página com o aviso em negrito.

É possível fazer a mesma coisa usando as *media queries* ou alguma função específica do CSS? Ou seja, existe alguma forma de verificar quando a largura da tela for menor que a sua altura apenas com CSS e alterar a propriedade `display` da div `#aviso`?

Comment: `@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }`
`@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testando com o `@media portrait / landscape` eu consegue esse resultado, repare que não tem medida de pixels, apenas a orientação do dispositivo

> The orientation CSS media feature can be used to test the orientation of the viewport.

Tradução: *"O recurso de mídia CSS de orientação pode ser usado para testar a orientação da viewport."*

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    #aviso {
        display: none;
    }
    #main {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    #aviso {
        display: block;
    }
    #main {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="aviso">
    <strong>Use o dispositivo na orientação horizontal!</strong>
</div>
<div id="main">
    Conteúdo
</div>
```

**OBS:** *Importante... Abrir o teclado virtual em vários dispositivos na orientação retrato fará com que a janela de visualização fique mais larga do que alta, fazendo com que o navegador use estilos de paisagem em vez de retrato.*

**Um Curiosidade:** No Chrome pelo menos o quadrado perfeito 1:1, (ex. 1000px x 1000px) é entendido como `portrait` e o CSS dele prevalece naturalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Massa! Mas não tem como usar só uma media query? Tipo, o que estiver fora ser o padrão?

Comment: @sim tem sim meu caro, só coloquei "completão" para fins didáticos. O padrão é mostrar o conteúdo "horizontal" imagino. Então ele ficaria fora do @media landscape, e vc faria uma regra apenas para `portrait`

Comment: Boto fé! Valeu! Vai servir bastante de referência a resposta.

Comment: @Sam olha o edit com a **OBS** que fiz... nem tudo são flores tb...

Comment: Ixi! Não tinha pensado nisso. Vou ter que ir atrás de uma gambeta pra ignorar o teclado. É nóis!